# Visual Studio 2017 with Redmine: How to configure

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, redmine, ankhsvn, redmine-plugins

My company uses SVN as their source control system, and Redmine as their issue tracker. We were using VS 2013 until now, that we started to use VS 2017 today. I could connect it to SVN through AnkhSVN, but I having problems to set it up to use Redmine as issue tracker.

In VS 2013, we used Nitkin Ankh Redmine connector, but it seems there's nothing like that for VS 2017.

How can I set Redmine as the VS 2017 issue tracker? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can always manage tickets thru svn comments like closes #23, etc via settings | repositories | keywords. As far as Nitkin Ankh connector, it's open source, why won't you upgrade it for VS 2017 and share with us... I have found this one, though https://github.com/rozpuszczalny/vscode-redmine

Comment: @AleksandarPavić Thanks for your help, but the extension you have found is for VS Code, not for VS 2017.